# Problems with Page slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

could you help me to figure this out?
I'm trying to use this page slide method from this

http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/942/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width();//get width automaticly
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width+"px" && !$(this).is(':animated'))
    {
        $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-='+slider_width});
    }
    else
    {
    if(!$(this).is(':animated'))//perevent double click to double margin
        {
            $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+='+slider_width});
        }
    }


  });
 });
```

and this is what I've been trying

http://jsfiddle.net/ejkim2000/f7DVK/

but I'm having some problems.

First problem I have is trigger button **place** gets margin so the sentence after **place** is being pushed. I deleted **#pollSlider-button** in this code

**$('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-='+slider_width}); }**

to disable the margin from button but ended up having the slide page keep sliding to the right. Is there any way that I can make the slide page work without having margin on a button?

Another problem is I input another button in slide page for closing action but It simply doesn't work and I can't even understand why. Hope somebody can help to make this closing button work.

Just your information, I'd like to use width and height with css because it'll be easier for me to make slide page responsive and I also would like to apply this method for other directions too.

Thanks a million!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ejkim2000/D2xVn/ This is the example of the page keep sliding to the right When I delete #pollSlider-button in this code $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-='+slider_width}); }

Comment: you cant have same id for more than one elements "pollSlider-button" is an id for the span element and you are creating another span element with same id, its not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Working** [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/D2xVn/6/)

This is with same button to close and open the slider

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width(); //get width automaticly
    $('#pollSlider-button').click(function () {
        if ($('.pollSlider').css("margin-right") == 0 + "px") {
            $('.pollSlider').animate({
                "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
            });
        } else {

            $('.pollSlider').animate({
                "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
            });

        }


    });
});
```

Try this

**Working** [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/D2xVn/7/)

This is with separate button for open and close

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width();
    $('#pollSlider-button').click(function () {   //open button
        if ($('.pollSlider').css("margin-right") == "-" + slider_width + "px") {
            $('.pollSlider').animate({
                "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
            });
        }
    });
 $('#pollSlider-button2').click(function () {  //close button with different id
        if ($('.pollSlider').css("margin-right") == 0 + "px") {
            $('.pollSlider').animate({
                "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you